# In England, why are some high schools called hospitals?

Tags: meaning, british-english

I noticed that in the UK some high schools are called hospitals. For example, [Grey Coat Hospital](https://www.gch.org.uk/),
[Christ's Hospital](https://www.christs-hospital.org.uk/) and [Queen Elizabeth's Hospital](https://www.qehbristol.co.uk/). Does *hospital* sometimes mean *school*?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144418/discussion-on-question-by-simd-in-england-why-are-some-high-schools-called-hosp); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: You might like to ask a separate question about the term "high school": the term exists but has a complex history and certainly isn't (at least in England) a generic term for all secondary education.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

These schools are ancient, some quite nearly predating even the modern sense of the word "hospital" as a place for the sick or injured which [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hospital) says formed in the 1540s. Instead, it's an [earlier connotation of the word "hospital"](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED21265), which also described:

- Places for weary travelers (a "hospice" in the old sense of that word)
- Almshouses
- [Retirement homes for sailors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Hospital,_London)

In other words, "hospitals" were all charitably run places which provided a refuge (or *hospital*ity) for some needy group. In the case of the schools, it was a place for youth to be, run by a charitable organization, where they could get an education. Some schools, like the [Royal Hospital School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Hospital_School), were formed not just for youth, but orphaned youth.

According to the [Lincoln Christ's Hospital School](https://christs-hospital.lincs.sch.uk/our-school/lchs-history/school-archive/152-lincoln-christ-s-hospital-school-the-origin-of-the-name) website:

> Dr Mary Lucas informs us that one of the definitions of 'hospital' in the Oxford English Dictionary is ‘a charitable institution for the education…of the young’. The name has long since disappeared as a general term for a school, but survives in ‘proper’ names such as Christ’s Hospital School, a prestigious public school founded in London in the 16th century and now relocated in Horsham.  Education was originally religious in intent and execution, and many schools and colleges, like churches, were given Saints’ or God's names (e.g. Trinity, All Souls, Christ’s).

(Note: a [public school in the British sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_school_(United_Kingdom)).)

---

I have never heard of a school in the United States with such a name, perhaps because schools here aren't old enough. There are "university hospitals" but these are entirely different beast: [teaching hospitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_hospital). Not to be confused with [hospital schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hospital_school) which are places for sick children to be taught while they are treated.

Comment: A fine example, next time you're in France, the *hospices de Beaune*, probably the ultimate remaining renaissance building.

Comment: @Fattie - Wow! Just been looking at photos of the inside and out. What an amazing place.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica right.  it gives me a thrill to mention it to someone who hasn't been or wasn't aware of it.  bizarrely I lived about a block away for some years!! :O   its also right in face of the justly famous market (Saturdays? I think!)

Comment: @Fattie If I was rich I would ask if I could buy a place like that and live there!

Comment: Also in France, Hôtel-Dieu means a hospital and not a hotel.

Comment: @Michael - we simply rented !!!  for a tiny fraction of the price of renting the equivalent in, say, sydney, NYC, or Tokyo!

Comment: @Fattie I don't understand, you rented a room at hospices de Beaune?

Comment: hi @Michael heh, the conversational threads got mixed up. we rented *a home* about *a block away* from the famous building in question. cheers

Answer (score 15):

The clue is in the Latin word from which 'hospital' is derived:  *hospitium*.  The Latin *hospes* means *guest* and in the Roman world refers to a place that receives guests on travel:  a sort hotel or guest house.  In the middle ages, when the language of the Christian religion was Latin it came to be charitable housing or provision, sometimes for the old, sometimes for the sick, and sometimes for the education of the poor.  The 'hospital' schools were at least originally boarding schools, as Christ's Hospital, for example, still is.  As it happens, my own father went to school there.  This was in part a charitable matter:  his father was a merchant sea officer at the time and was deemed to meet the then school's criteria by being the eldest of a family of five.  At the time, the school taught not only academic subjects but practical engineering, wood and ironwork, and had its own farm.  Since then, these more charitable aspects have been pared back and the charitable aspect has faded, not entirely but to a substantial degree in the face of competition for examination results and of rising costs.  But it was in part because of that school that my father became a civil engineer.  In earlier centuries, hospital schools might be more likely to recruit its graduates into a religious life (church or monastery) or into administrative roles.

Note that we also have the word 'hospitality', which refers to the world of food, alcohol and the hotel (the French for which retains the 's', as in *hostel*, in the circumflex accent of *hôtel*).  Care for the sick, old and poor was an important use of *hospitia*.

Comment: Trust Toffy, Guys. 'Hospital' today does not mean what 'hospital' meant hundreds of years ago

Comment: If you really want to dig, it means "stranger."  This is also the root of the word "hostile."

Comment: And English "guest" and "host" are both divergent forms of the same word used to represent two complementary concepts :)